# Convert a unicode to characters

Tags: php, unicode

I try to build Tagging System in vBulletin forum and it works fine.

But I have a problem with the quick edit of a post (using AJAX).

If I write the characters is in Hebrew language, it will replace the characters to Unicode.

An example of that when I write a post in the Hebrew language:

```
חחחחח לא?test!!
```

It will become to this:

```
%u05D7%u05D7%u05D7%u05D7%u05D7 %u05DC%u05D0?test!!
```

Comment: You know that you are allowed to also post a real question here?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though the deprecated javascipt function [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) is being used to encode the string. If you're echoing this out in the webpage via JavaScript, you could use [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vathhgsv/). As mentioned above however, this is deprecated.

The functions that should instead be used are [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in place of `escape()`, and [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) in place of `unescape()`. Then, you can use [`urldecode()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) inside PHP to get the result you want, if this is a necessary step.

---

Given your current setup, to convert the unicode characters to html entities appropriate for rendering in a browser, the following should do what you want:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/%u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UCS-2BE');
}, $str);
```

Comment: If i don't try using the tagging system in post and write hebrew, its works fine. it happen only when i try to use tagging and hebrew charters. and i need solution in php or way to fix the bug..

Comment: ty, it works! now i have more one question, when i do normal post in hebrew, it makes the characters in mysql in gibberish, and when i using the tagging system with ur fix, it makes the characters in mysql in HTML unicode or something like that. it ok but it take space in table and pref it be in gibberish, so have some way to do it? and thanks again i tried to fix week ago

Comment: @almog  It looks like you've applied my fix before the code is stored in the database. If you want it to be stored how it used to be, apply the fix when the program is getting the text to display from the database, just before sending it to the browser.

Comment: here is my code: http://pastebin.com/8b1hBes3 i try do what u said, it still don't works fine. any ideas ?

Comment: i fix it but now have new bug it look like "×”×× ×™×¢×‘×•×“ ABCD למה לא %u05D1" how can i fix it? @enigma